# Cannot assign "Note.user" must be a "User" instance. Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am getting the following error on running my django code. I am an absolute beginner and I was following a tutorial to create a crud app.

On typing the information in my html form I get the following error

> ValueError: Cannot assign django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x00000288775D3EF0: "Note.user" must be a "User" instance

from `form.instance.user = request.user` in my views.py

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Note

# Create your views here.

from .forms import NoteModelForm


# CRUD - create update retrieve and delete

def createView(request):
    form = NoteModelForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.user = request.user
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, "create.html", context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Note

class NoteModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ['title','url','image']
```

create.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CRUD APP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `request.user.is_authenticated` is True?

Comment: I think your request user is annonymous user so check it when assigning

Comment: @art06 I am not sure what does that mean. Where do I put that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user is not logged in, `request.user` gives AnonymousUser, which can't be assigned to the form instance.

To avoid this situation, you may add a condition before accessing the view. For this, you may use [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator, as shown below

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def createView(request):
    ....
```